# Unique behavior of my program , Unable to identify

Tags: c++, visual-c++

There is some problem during the run time of my program and i am unable to get what the problem is.

what happens basically is , my program automatically closes and displays the following in **Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express** window

[image]

What could be the reasons for this ? I have no idea why this is happening.

*Let me tell that in my program i have used pointers too often and have used character arrays which i write to the disc*

**The program is too large to display**

This is the function called after which my program stops :

```
void display_databases()
{


 struct info_of_trains
 {
int train_no;
char train_name[25];
char boarding_pt[25];
char destination[25];
int first_seats;
int fare_first;
int second_seats;
int fare_second;
char  date[20];
    };



    info_of_trains e;

  cout<<"TRno.  TRname     B.pt    D.pt    F.seats    F.fare   S.seats   F.second   Date\n";
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("database","r");
  if(fp==NULL)
  {
cout<<"failure";
  }
  else
  {
  while(fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp)==1)
  {

printf(e.train_no,e.train_name,e.boarding_pt,e.destination,e.first_seats,e.fare_first,e.second_seats,e.fare_second,e.date);
  cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
   }
   fclose(fp);
   }
   }
```

This is where execution stops :!

Comment: "printf(e.train_no," -- e.train_no has type int, but you told printf to use it as a pointer to a string.  The supposed string might be in an invalid memory location, or it might not conform to printf's requirement for a format string.

Comment: Also, since you are using C++, you would be better off if you acually used all the nice standard classes which help you write less error-prone code. You could open a new question about tips to convert it to C++.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have hit a breakpoint, or your program had an access violation (reading an illegal pointer). You also seem to have maximized/detached the debugging panels. You can reattach the panel by dragging the yellow bar at the top to the lower part of the screen.

Did you recieve a warning message before it happened? Otherwise, did you define a breakpoint (clicking in the left margin of the code editor, so a red circle appears there)

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, the error occurs because you use `printf` the wrong way. Use `cout` instead, as you did above:

```
cout << e.train_no <<" " <<  e.train_name << " " << e.boarding_pt << " " << e.destination << " " << e.first_seats << " " << e.fare_first << " " << e.second_seats << " " << e.fare_second << " " << e.date << endl;
```

Comment: Ok, but that could mean either a breakpoint or a bad pointer still, you just might not always hit them. If you do as I proposed, and attach the debugging panel in the lower part of the screen you should be able to see the code where execution has stopped. Also, note that you can try to resume execution by pressing the little "play" icon that is just below "save"

Comment: i have posted some code..Can you please tell clearly what should i do to check where the execution stopped ?

Comment: Ok, in your picture, there is a yellow bar with the text "Locals". If you click and drag on that bar to the lower center part of the screen (there should be a little icon there now), the lower part should get a blue tint. Release the mouse button. You have now docked the panel to the bottom of the screen, and should be able to see your code again.